Pyrolysis of regolith can produce hydrogen and oxygen. Is this a viable alternative to water hydrolysis for production of lunar H2/O2 propellant?
With the currently proposed lunar polar landings, there has been  speculation about electrolysis of water for the production of hydrogen and oxygen for propellant. Electrolysis requires generous electricity supply. This is problematic due to the difficulty of manufacturing solar panels in situ, their low efficiency, and the difficulty of removing dust.
An alternative would be pyrolysis of regolith using solar thermal energy. A counter-current auger kiln would heat regolith and gasses would be drawn off in fractions, much like a still.

Counter-current processes are used in industry (and biological organisms) to generate temperature gradients while conserving energy.
The kiln and augers rotate as a unit. Since the augers have opposite "handedness", regolith is transported first one way, then the other. This countercurrent maintains the temperature gradient along the kiln.
The pyrolytic facility could be located away from the hypothesized water deposits at the Lunar poles, since even non-polar regolith has a significant percentage of water.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328625207_In-situ_resource_utilization-feasibility_of_the_use_of_lunar_soil_to_create_structures_on_the_moon_via_sintering_based_additive_manufacturing_technology/figures?lo=1

The oxide-rich lunar surface regolith can be used to extract the
oxygen needed for the future of lunar exploration efforts as a
consumable for life-support systems and spacecraft propulsion. Various
techniques for the extraction of oxygen have been developed already,
with solar vapor-phase pyrolysis shown to be a promising yet
understudied approach. In contrast to other techniques, it requires
only locally available resources, such as unbeneficiated regolith,
sunlight, and vacuum in order to liberate oxygen and oxygen-bearing
molecules.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576524004399
• The Lunar CRater Observation and Sensing Satellite mission launched
along with the lunar orbiter was directed to impact the lunar surface.
Observations of the resulting 10-mile-high plume showed that nearly
five percent of the regolith was composed of water and another five
percent contained additional volatiles including methane, ammonia,
hydrogen, carbon dioxide, and carbon monoxide.

https://www.nasa.gov/overview-in-situ-resource-utilization

Some things to consider: How much energy would be required for both systems, including product separation for pyrolysis & how does one obtain separate streams of clean H2 & O2 if pyrolysis were to be used? Also, what would happen to the other products of pyrolysis?

Both electrolysis and pyrolysis share the need for significant material handling of regolith. The big difference is the primary energy input: solar electric or solar thermal. Because of the inherent inefficiency of solar panels, a much larger collector area would be needed than for solar thermal. Gasses are easily separated by cryogenic distillation.: pyrolytic production during the heat of day, cryogenic separation during the cold of night.

Not only O2 and H2 is produced, there is also CO and CO2 which should be separated from the O2. Oxygen used for life support should contain no CO. "Indoors CO is one of the most acutely toxic contaminants affecting indoor air quality" (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide)

@Uwe .. that is correct. Even worse, it is a chronically toxic as well as acutely toxic. That's why it is a concern in the O2 produced by the MOXIE system. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51636/is-moxies-oxygen-ready-to-breathe-or-is-there-co2-and-or-co-that-would-need-to
